# Parse excel spreadsheet using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to create a data frame where I fetch only "NOK" status. Based on the status, I retrieve the validation number and fill under issue column. The number of columns in each validation can vary. How do I iterate through the rows to get exact status for every validation. Can anyone please help, I am new to Python.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
df =    pd.read_excel('C:\Excel_Query.xlsx', header=[0,2]); 
df.to_dict()
```

This is the result I get:

```
{('Key', 'werwer'): {0: 'qweqwe', 1: 'ertert'},
 ('site', 1232): {0: 2424, 1: 68678},
 ('work order', 1): {0: 2, 1: 3},
 ('project', 11): {0: 22, 1: 33},
 ('start date', 'Unnamed: 4_level_1'): {0: nan, 1: nan},
 ('end date', 'Unnamed: 5_level_1'): {0: nan, 1: nan},
 ('duration', 'Unnamed: 6_level_1'): {0: nan, 1: nan},
 ('Software Center', 'Status'): {0: 'NOK', 1: 'OK'},
 ('Software Center', 'Validate'): {0: 0, 1: 0},
 ('Software Center', 'Confirm'): {0: 'NOK', 1: 0},
 ('Test training', 'Status'): {0: 'NOK', 1: 'OK'},
 ('Test training', 'Validate'): {0: 'NOK', 1: 0},
 ('Test training', 'Check'): {0: 'NOK', 1: 0},
 ('Test training', 'Check2'): {0: 'NOK', 1: 0},
 ('Test training', 'Config'): {0: nan, 1: 0.0},
 ('Test training', 'Config2'): {0: nan, 1: 0.0},
 ('Test training', 'Issue'): {0: nan, 1: 0.0},
 ('Work Release', 'Status'): {0: 'OK', 1: 'NOK'},
 ('Work Release', 'Check'): {0: 0, 1: 'OK'},
 ('Work Release', 'Vendor'): {0: 0, 1: 'OK'},
 ('Work Release', 'Issue'): {0: 0, 1: 'OK'},
 ('Work Release', 'Swap'): {0: 0.0, 1: nan},
 ('Work Release', 'Swap.1'): {0: nan, 1: nan},
 ('Issue 1', 'Unnamed: 23_level_1'): {0: 'Software Center', 1: 'Work Release'},
 ('Issue2', 'Unnamed: 24_level_1'): {0: 'Test training', 1: nan},
 ('Issue 3', 'Unnamed: 25_level_1'): {0: nan, 1: nan}}
```

I want to filter only Status containing "NOK" and populate that corresponding header under the issue column

Comment: please add a sample of your data to your question (not as image, as text!). You want to filter already when importing the data or is it ok to import the whole sheet and then filter in the df.

Comment: you need to be a bit more clear what your goal is. you have different numbers of validations (with different number of columns). the goal is to fill these cells of issue if all columns of validation are `NOK` ? Last time I checked this question it said you want to filter the data. This looks different now. Since you are new to SO, please have a look here on [`how to ask a good question`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Rabinzel : The goal is to check every status under the validation. Every validation is to be considered as one cluster or group. There can be any number of columns under a validation. 
For ex: consider row1, 
validation1 and validation2 status are "NOK". Hence we fill that value under "Issue 1" and "Issue 2" respectively. whereas "Issue 3" is left blank as validation3 status is "OK".
Similarly for row2, only validation3 status is "NOK". Hence we fill it under "issue 1".
Its like whichever status is "NOK", we keep filling the issue with that particular validation number

Comment: ok, think I got it now. Pleaseadd these information to your question, it should include everything it is needed to understand your goal. Since you still ignore to add some data to your question, I want to be pretty clear. People usually won't help you if they have to create your sample data from scratch. Provide the data and you'll see, an answer is not far away ;) here is what you do now. run this code and copy paste the result to the question: `df = pd.read_excel('name_of_the_excel_file.xlsx', header=[0,1]);
df.to_dict()`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it the most elegant way, but here is one way to do it.
You filter the df with `.loc` to get all rows with the columns `Status`, then with list comprehension change the values from 'NOK' to 'Validation' (with a counter as suffix) and apply those list with length 3 (because 3 validations) with `pd.Series` to those 3 columns with `Issue`.
Is your data always fixed 3 Validations (with different number of columns) or do also the number of validations change?

```
res =  (df.loc(axis=1)[:,'Status'].apply(lambda row: 
                                         pd.Series([f'Validation_{num}' if val=='NOK' else np.nan for num, val in enumerate(row, 1)])
                                         ,axis=1))
print(res)
```

Output `res` is a df:

```
              0             1             2
0  Validation_1  Validation_2           NaN
1           NaN           NaN  Validation_3
```

Now assign `res` to the `Issue` columns:

```
df[['Issue 1', 'Issue 2', 'Issue 3']] = res
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Validation 1                  Validation 2                                            Validation 3                                     Issue 1             Issue 2             Issue 3
        Status Validate Confirm       Status Validate Check Check2 Config Config2 Issue       Status Check Vendor Issue Swap Unnamed: 15_leVel_1 Unnamed: 16_leVel_1 Unnamed: 17_leVel_1
0          NOK        0     NOK          NOK      NOK   NOK    NOK    NaN     NaN   NaN           OK     0      0     0  0.0        Validation_1        Validation_2                 NaN
1           OK        0       0           OK        0     0      0    0.0     0.0   0.0          NOK    OK     OK    OK  NaN                 NaN                 NaN        Validation_3
```

You don't need to save the first step as `res` and assign `res` to the original df, you can do that directly. It was just for demonstration purpose.

Comment: you're welcome. Are these Issue columns also always already there for Issue 1,2,.....n? Or do we have to create them

Comment: if there is free text instead of validation 1, 2, 3 etc. how do we iterate instead of using f'Validation_{num}.  currently there are more than 30 free text columns. 
Issue columns are already present. we just need to populate it.